# Format words around a center letter

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using reactjs to present text that looks like i't moving through an old-time typewriter.   In order to style the text, I have divided it into elements per-word, like this:

```
<div><span>HUMPTY </span><span>DUMPTY </span><span>SAT </span></div>
```

To be like a typewriter, I want a specific letter of one of the words (say, the 'S' in 'SAT') to be exactly centered in the container.  I've tried breaking that word into spans, like this:

```
<span>S</span><span>A</span><span>T</span>
```

And now I'd like to place, say, the `<span>A</span>` in the precise center of the containing div, and have the rest of the text fall to the left and to the right (overflowing, not wrapping, if necessary).

I tried styling the containing div as "flex" and telling it to justify with "space-around", but that spreads the words out.  I've also tried styling the center span with "margin 0" but that doesn't center that div for some reason.

Can someone help me get this effect I've described?

Comment: Unclear. Can you post an illustration or the full code you've tried? (I have no idea how a typewriter aligns text; I began on WordPerfect.)

Comment: I was around when typewriters were used :) .. we learned how to use them in school .... I have more trouble with `flexbox` :), so what about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/myh2n9hz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now I'd like to place, say, the A in the precise center of the containing div, and have the rest of the text fall to the left and to the right [...]

Not an expert in using flexbox, but at least I got this part to work by dividing the text into three parts and using the flex-basis property. Probably it will need some fine-tuning for the wrapping part and for handling the spacing between the parts correctly.

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: flex;
}

span:first-child,
span:last-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

/* from here for demo purposes only */

span.centered {
  color: red;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

p:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div><span>HUMPTY DUMPTY S</span><span class="centered">A</span><span>T</span></div>

<p>center</p>
```

Comment: thanks.  i added a lot more style, but this got me going (in particular the flex-basis thing)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understood what you were looking for, but this is what I imagined you were describing. I used `text-indent` and some trial and error to get the proper calculations. Some of this might degrade across different browsers but you may be able to alleviate by using a Google Font and [style reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[image]

(See the working demo below)

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.type');

function char(n){

  var indent = -1*(n-1) + (.2 * (n-1))
  //console.log(n, indent)
  el.style.textIndent = indent+'em';

}

for( var i = 1; i<el.innerText.length+1; i++ ){
  setTimeout(char.bind(this, i), 500*i)
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.type {
  width: 1.6em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: solid 1px;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%, #eee 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="type">HUMPTY</div>
```

Comment: super helpful, thanks!  The other answer suited me a little better.

Answer (score 0):

A wee hack

```
<div class="bla" contenteditable>
bla
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bla {
  width: 51%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[el fidlé](https://jsfiddle.net/uxyro5vg/)

Not really an answer as only works for 1 line but maybe you can take it somewhere from there.